# Generate "spherical" panorama in 3D software

Tags: 3d, rendering, blender, panoramas

Lets say I have a 3D model of room in some format. How can I programmatically render "spherical" panorama from some point of room (kind of like the "Google street view" uses)?

I suppose it can be done in Blender?

It's better if it will be done in Linux.

Comment: This should probably not be a community wiki question, since it's not about opinions but about a concrete problem.

Comment: I made it community wiki so others can change or re-formulate question. English is not my main language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say your best bet is to render [cube maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_map) and convert these to the desired projection. IIRC [HDRshop](http://gl.ict.usc.edu/HDRShop/) is able to convert cube maps to [sphere maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_mapping). To render a cube map, just point a camera with 90° FOV along each positive and negative coordinate axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a static image, render the images like Malte says, and stitch them back together with http://hugin.sourceforge.net/

If you were looking for something interactive, you can render it in the blender game engine, and look around inside, or even project it into a dome.